# How to fire an ajax request on rad wizard step change

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have created 2 radwizard steps dynamically, i want to fire an ajax request on step change. How can i do this?

Thanks.

```
Markup:
 <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WizardUCDemo.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebUIFrameWork.UITemplate.WizardUCDemo" %>

    <div style="overflow:inherit">
    <telerik:RadWizard runat="server" RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="wizardControl"
        DisplayProgressBar="false" ProgressBarPosition="Right" NavigationBarPosition="Right"
        NavigationButtonsPosition="Bottom" DisplayNavigationButtons="false">
    </telerik:RadWizard>
</div>

userControl.ascx.cs:
public void GenerateSteps()
 RadWizardStep step;
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
   step = new RadWizardStep();
   step.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
   step.ID = "step_1"+i.ToString();
   wizardControl.WizardSteps.Add(step);
}
aspx.cs:
protected void rbtnAddControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WizardUCDemo.GenerateSteps();
    }
protected void RadAjaxManager1_AjaxRequest(object sender, AjaxRequestEventArgs e)
{

}
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Dkrf.png)

Comment: can you show your html code?

Comment: I had edited the code can you please check @VijunavVastivch

Comment: what do you mean `i want to fire an ajax request on step change`?

Comment: I have add a image how ui is,  in that i have 2 steps on click of 2nd step control should go to **RadAjaxManager1_AjaxRequest**.

Comment: you can use `OnClick="RadAjaxManager1_AjaxRequest"`

Comment: Thanks for the idea, this resolve the problem ** var radManager = $find('<%= RadAjaxManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).ClientID %>'); radManager.ajaxRequest("StepChange&");**